# Setuptools. How to make package contain extra data folder and all folders inside

Tags: python, filenames, setuptools

So i'm making setuptool package.

To include extra data files in package i need to specefy `data_file` parameter inside `setup()`.

**Code Example:**

```
datadir = os.path.join('share','data')
datafiles = [(datadir, [f for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(datadir, '*'))])]
import metainfo # a file with relevant information
setup(
    name             = 'yourpackage',
    version          = metainfo.version,
    maintainer       = metainfo.maintainer,
    maintainer_email = metainfo.maintainer_email,
    author           = metainfo.authors,
    author_email     = metainfo.authors,
    description      = metainfo.description,
    keywords         = metainfo.keywords,
    long_description = metainfo.long_description,

    # package installation
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir  = package_dir,

    data_files = datafiles,
}
```

`datafile` variable in this example will contain data like this

```
[('share/data', ['share/data/addon.xml.tmplt', 'share/data/default.py.tmplt'])]
```

However, my example  does not make list of folders and containing files recursively.

I need function which gets as parameter folder_path and returns list of tuple:

```
[
    ('share/data', ['share/data/addon.xml.tmplt', 'share/data/default.py.tmplt']),
    ('share/data/inside', ['share/data/inside/file.iside', 'share/data/inside/file2.inside']),
    .........

]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to generate that information:

```
datafiles = [(root, [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files])
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(datadir)]
```

That'll produce absolute paths; you can process the `root` variable a little more to make them relative to the `setup.py` directory if needed.

Comment: you may use `[(root, glob.glob(root/**/*.*, recursive=True)]`

Comment: @warownia1: no, because that doesn't create `(directorypath, list_of_files_in_directory)` tuples *per directory*.